# In python How to check if the element exist inside the dictionary values if the dictionary value is a list of numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

for example below dict:

```
ID={'A':[127, 130, 123, 210, 109, 128, 204]}
```

How do I check if the dict value list contains the user input ID?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that there are going to be more than one Key in the dict so I modified it to show it working with that.

Try something like this:

```py
ID={'A':[127, 130, 123, 210, 109, 128, 204], 'C':[227, 330, 423, 510, 609, 728, 804]}
input_ID = 333

def check_ID(inputID):

    for val_list in ID.values():
        if inputID in val_list:
            return True

    return False

found = check_ID(input_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach iterates over and looks in each dictionary key's container list.

```
def id_in_dict(id_, dc):
    """Check if an id exists in a dictionary:list of values structure"""
    for k in list(dc.keys()):
        if id_ in dc[k]:
            return "found"
    return "not found"
```

```
ID = {'A': [127, 130, 123, 210, 109, 128, 204], 'X': [27, 109, 3]}
id_in_dict(204, ID)  # A
id_in_dict(3, ID)  # B
id_in_dict(109, ID)  # A and B
id_in_dict(10000, ID)  # not A not B
```

Returns:
`"found"`
`"found"`
`"found"`
`"not found"`